# SharePoint Inetgration with Peoplesoft using TIBCO API Gateway

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-integration

Would like to know how to integrate SP 2013 with TIBCO API Gateway.
If I explain a little bit about my requirements,client is having different systems like, PeopleSoft, Jabber. And they want to integrate these systems with SP 2013 with the help of TIBCO API Gateway.
So can anyone  point me some links/sources.

Comment: May I know,why its off-topic? I am looking for source code/ samples. So if anyone has those samples they can provide me the source code.I think this is not off-topic, since  its'a programming question